# How to permanently remove item from array after it's index is called?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

My following code displays a question and its matching answer by making an array of keys and values from a dictionary and making sure both arrays have the same index that is pulled. However after a question and its answers are randomly selected I want to remove them permanently from their respective arrays until all the other items in the array have been displayed. Simply put, how can I make sure a question and set of answers are not shown again until all the items are shown or until the user gets an answer wrong? As of now my code only makes sure the same random index isn't chosen twice in a row when I want to make sure it isn't shown twice at all.

Here is my code (swift for iOS):

```
func randomQuestion() {


    //random question
    var questionList = Array(QADictionary.keys)
    var rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questionList.count)))
    questionLabel.text = questionList[rand]




    //matching answers
    var answerList = Array(QADictionary.values)
    var choices = answerList[rand]




        rightAnswerBox = arc4random_uniform(4)+1

        //create button
        var button:UIButton = UIButton()
        var x = 1



        for index in 1...4
        {

            button = view.viewWithTag(index) as! UIButton

            if (index == Int(rightAnswerBox))
            {
                button.setTitle(choices[0], for: .normal)

            }

            else {
                button.setTitle(choices[x], for: .normal)
                x += 1

            }

            func removePair() {
                questionList.remove(at: rand)
                answerList.remove(at: rand)


            }


            randomImage()

        }
    }


let QADictionary = ["Who is Thor's brother?" : ["Atum", "Loki", "Red Norvell", "Kevin Masterson"], "What is the name of Thor's hammer?" : ["Mjolinr", "Uru", "Stormbreaker", "Thundara"], "Who is the father of Thor?" : ["Odin", "Sif", "Heimdall", "Balder"]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `questionList` to a property of the viewController so that it stays around from one call of `randomQuestion` to the next.  Reload it only when it is empty.

Use the dictionary to find the matching answers instead of using a second array.

```
var questionList = [String]()

func randomQuestion() {

    //if no more questions, reload the questionList
    if questionList.isEmpty {
        questionList = Array(QADictionary.keys)
    }

    var rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questionList.count)))
    questionLabel.text = questionList[rand]

    //matching answers
    var choices = QADictionary[questionList[rand]]!

    questionList.remove(at: rand)

    rightAnswerBox = arc4random_uniform(4)+1

    //create button
    var button:UIButton = UIButton()
    var x = 1

    for index in 1...4
    {
        button = view.viewWithTag(index) as! UIButton

        if (index == Int(rightAnswerBox))
        {
            button.setTitle(choices[0], for: .normal)

        }
        else {
            button.setTitle(choices[x], for: .normal)
            x += 1

        }

        func removePair() {
            questionList.remove(at: rand)
        }

        randomImage()
    }
}
```

Comment: this code still does not suffice for what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm trying to make sure once a question from the array is asked it isn't asked again

Comment: Did you try it?  You might need to move where you call `questionList.remove(at: rand)` to the appropriate place.  Do you want to remove the question immediately upon choosing it, or only when they get it right?

Comment: Yes when I wrote the code like you said I got an error under the matching answer comment for the choices variable that said "cannot call value of non-function type '[String : Array<String>]'"

Comment: I want to remove immediately upon choosing it because once any question is answered wrong I want the app to reset and all the asked question to be placed back into the array

Comment: Remove the question right after getting the choices.  I updated the answer.

Comment: To reset, just set `questionList = []` and it will reload the next time you call `randomQuestion`.

Comment: Thank you!! Your update to the code worked. And where would I place the reset question list code in order for the array of questions to reset after an question has been answered wrong?

Comment: In your button handling code, when they've chosen a wrong answer, set `questionList = []`.

Comment: thank you you've been more than helpful I appreciate it very much.

Comment: Do you have an email or another way of contact if I have any more questions?

Comment: Ok once the user gets the question right I want to segue to a "correct, continue?" view controller to where it says correct answer and they the press a button to continue the quiz. How do I make sure they continue on to the next question where they left of at when they press continue on the "correct, continue?" view controller? right now when I run the simulator once you press the button the data does not stay updated and you're liable to get the question you just answered again but it hasn't registered the answer. I only want it to reset the question array if the answer is wrong, not right

Comment: That's an appropriate topic for a new question. SO discourages discussions of additional questions in the comments because it future visitors will not easily find them.  Make sure you show how you're doing it now.